# CMake is linking againts library's full path

Tags: build, cmake

Okay I have a project in CMake structured like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt
/libfoo/CMakeLists.txt
/frontend/qt/CMakeLists.txt
```

`libfoo` is a library I'm writing and `frontend/qt` is a small frontend and also an example of usage. The problem is that CMake passes the relative path to `libfoo.so.x` to the linker instead of an `-l` option. The Qt gui target is declared like this:

```
add_executable(qtgui ${qtgui_sources} ${qtgui_moced} ${qtgui_ui_h})
target_link_libraries(qtgui ${QT_LIBRARIES} foo)
```

I'd rather it just linked againts `-lfoo` like all other libs, not the full path.
How to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, never mind, found it:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling

I obviously didn't google enough, sorry.